# React: Re-render sets state to initial value even after calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am new to React and this is my first time asking a question on StackOverFlow so my apologies if my question is lame or if i missed some post guildelines.

I get the value for the setState in a function which is passed as a prop to child component:

```js
const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState(null);

const handleTextAreaChange = (newTextAreaValue) => {
        return setTextAreaValue(newTextAreaValue);
    };
```

The textAreaValue isn't updated immediately, which is understandable considering React schedules such requests.

I have another function called textFile(), which is triggered when a user clicks a button.

```js
const TextFile = (value) => {
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        console.log(textAreaValue);// outputs null
        const file = new Blob([textAreaValue], {
            type: "text/html",
        });
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.download = "myFile.html";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
    };
```

As seen in the comment the state update isn't reflected.

To know if the state change happens, i setup a useEffect, and logged the value of textAreaValue and it does show the updated value.

So my guess is, whenever the state is re-rendered, the state value is set to the initial value, that is null.
I am scratching my head here, i would really like to know what is happening here and how i can resolve this issue.

Here's the complete code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import JoditEditor from "../../src/";


const From = () => {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState({
        readonly: false,
        toolbar: true,
        extraButtons: [
            {
                name: "Save to file",
                icon: "fa fa-superscript",
                mode: 3,
                exec: function (a, b, c, d) {
                    debugger;
                    TextFile();
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState(null);
    const _setTextAreaValue = (textval) => {
        setTextAreaValue(textval);
        setTextAreaValue((state) => {
            console.log("after setstate", state); // correct update value;
            return state;
        });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        //debugger;
        console.log("inside use effect");
        console.log(textAreaValue);
    });

    const TextFile = () => {
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        console.log("inside writetotext", textAreaValue);
        const file = new Blob([textAreaValue], {
            type: "text/html",
        });
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.download = "myFile.html";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
    };

    const handleBlurAreaChange = (areaValue, event) => {
        console.log("before handleBlurAreaChange", textAreaValue, event); //null
        _setTextAreaValue(areaValue);
        console.log("after handleBlurAreaChange", textAreaValue); //null
    };

    const handleTextAreaChange = (newTextAreaValue) => {
        //debugger;
        console.log("before handleTextAreaChange", textAreaValue); //null
        _setTextAreaValue(newTextAreaValue);
        console.log(" after handleTextAreaChange", textAreaValue); //null
        return;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <JoditEditor
                config={config}
                onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
                onBlur={handleBlurAreaChange}
                value={textAreaValue}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default From;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the parameter inside the function below:

```
const _setTextAreaValue = (textval)
```

Can you try to change it as below:

```
const _setTextAreaValue = (e) => {
setTextAreaValue(e.target.value)
console.log(textAreaValue)
}
```